# HTML responsive photo grid picture size

Tags: html, grid, responsive

I want to make a responsive photo grid were the cells will have different sizes. I'm using few banner templates to calculate exactly the cells size I want in order to fit on the screen. Do I need to resize the pictures to the size of the cells or there is any kind of autofit so the images will resize and keep the ratio to fir the cells?.
Best Regards,

Joaquim Pinto

Comment: See here for simple ways to do it https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp

Comment: Please post the code you've tried. Helps if we can reproduce what you're seeing.